# Creating a zip file of the src folder using Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, zip

Having no knowledge of how gradle really works and how to use it well (I just copy paste snippets here and there), I was wondering if it was possible to ask gradle to generate a zip file containing the "src" folder of my Android app when I do generate the signed apk?

It sounds strange, but I want some hard copy in addition to all the source control things included in Android Studio, just in case (as I don't manage well what would be the equivalent of source control for Photoshop and Illustrator...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at [Gradle Distribution Plugin](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html)

According to the [documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) you might have to do the following things.

In your `build.gradle` add somewhere on top:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'
```

You can then just run `gradle distZip` and accoriding to the docs:

> You can run “gradle distZip” to package the main distribution as a
>   ZIP, or “gradle distTar” to create a TAR file. To build both types of
>   archives just run gradle assembleDist. The files will be created at
>   “$buildDir/distributions/$project.name-$project.version.«ext»”.

Or you can play with some options, if you'd like to.
To add data to be packed and to set output folder add:

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = 'someName'
        contents {
            from { 'src/readme' }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin:'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "file://some/repo")
        }
    }
}
```

And to start deployment you should execute in the command line:

```
gradle distZip
```

Hope it helps